# Sikuli and it's effectiveness with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sikuli

I am researching a proof of concept for the automation tool Sikuli, and I work primarily at a .NET shop. I see a lot of videos using this product with Java and Eclipse. My question is simply:

> Does this product work as well on microsoft products? or at all with
>   .NET?

If it does, are there any good starting point tutorials? so I can start to familiarize myself with it?

Comment: Sikuli work great with C#.net, Yes but there is no video on Youtube due to that I have created one , please take a look : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGVMbFMBfI8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three .Net wrappers for Sikuli.
Personally, I was a bit disappointed in all of them.

**Edit**: there was a [small bug in SikuliSharp](https://github.com/christianrondeau/SikuliSharp/issues/8) which was causing commands to Sikuli to fail. Now that this is working, I'm a happy SikuliSharp user.

- SikuliSharp: looked most promising, couldn't get it to work with the same images that worked for Sikuli4Net (see [SikuliSharp versus Sikuli4Net - why can't I get the first to work?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22507/sikulisharp-versus-sikuli4net-why-cant-i-get-the-first-to-work))
- Sikuli4Net - only one I got to work, but stopping the API launcher throws an exception... Also, it's not very fast.
- SikuliIntegrator - buh.

If you search NuGet manager in VS you'll easily find them all.

Comment: Edit: as of now, SikuliSharp does work and it's pretty easy to use.