# SikuliSharp versus Sikuli4Net - why can't I get the first to work?

Tags: sikuli

So, I'm trying to combine `Sikuli` with Selenium tests in C#.

`Sikuli4Net` is working, but `SikuliSharp` isn't doing anything except not finding the images. They are however the exact same ones I'm using for both wrappers.

What am I missing?

**Sikuli4Net**:

```
Screen gHome = new Screen();
Pattern gLogo = new Pattern(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Resources\\google-logo.PNG");
Pattern gSearch = new Pattern(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Resources\\google-search.JPG");
Pattern xResult = new Pattern(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Resources\\abc-detail.JPG");

Assert.IsTrue(gHome.Exists(gLogo, 7));
gHome.Type(gSearch, "abc");
Assert.IsTrue(gHome.Exists(xResult, 7));
```

**SikuliSharp**:

```
using (var session = Sikuli.CreateSession())
{
    var gLogo = Patterns.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Resources\\google-logo.PNG");
    var gSearch = Patterns.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Resources\\google-search.JPG");
    var xResult = Patterns.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Resources\\abc-detail.JPG");

    session.Exists(gLogo, 7);
    session.Wait(gSearch, 7);
    session.Type("abc");
    session.Exists(xResult, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in SikuliSharp is the 'culture sensitivity' in `string.Format()`, which caused a float to be passed as 0,7 instead of 0.7.

For details: https://github.com/christianrondeau/SikuliSharp/issues/8